# How does this controller detect both sides?

Tags: how-does-it-work

I've come across an old joystick, which I presume worked at the time (I have no way to tell, since it uses the old serial port). Naturally I got curious how it was made and opened it up. [image: controller to far right][image: controller to far left][image: controller to the center]

The black part you see does not conduct electricity at all. There seems to be no wires connecting the top right part, so while the state in second image conducts the electricity I don't see how the state could be reported. The same story is with the back and forward control. I've thought that it might only support two states, but that makes a pretty bad joystick, so I figured it must detect the state somehow, despite there being no wires. How does it work?

Comment: The red wire to track is the moving wiper The black is stationary and the other fixed side is not used. It appears to be 150k.

Comment: `uses the old serial port` ... probably not serial ... please post a picture of the connector, and the outside of the controller

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/52DNv here's some more images, @jsotola

Comment: it looks like a PC joystick connector ... https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/connectors/input_device/joystick-pc-gameport/

Comment: actually, the connector looks like the one for the NEO GEO AES

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 you were right, the resistance between the two sides shows as 140kΩ on one size and close to 0 on the other

Comment: Not sure if this is the identical configuration, but it certainly seems like there's strong overlap. The black dead zone is the only thing giving me some pause. EEVBLOG did a fairly in-depth explanation of the old joystick system. Either way probably worth a watch. https://youtu.be/hMBbnWjbUAU

Comment: nice, thanks for the video, it provides a great explanation!